# Passing data between Wordpress 'pages'

Tags: wordpress, environment-variables, session-variables

I have a menu, when the user clicks on any menu item, I want to take them to the *same page*, but I want to style the page differently depending on the menu item...for ex: change the background color to be different.
What's the best way to do this?  I was thinking that when they click on a menu item, a variable can be set or a session variable can be set.

Is there an easier way to do this?  Does Wordpress have anything built into the architecture to make this easy?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719087/multi-dimensional-array-post-from-form/5070123#5070123

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the session for this. Since HTTP is a stateless protocol, you should avoid using session to the greatest lengths possible. Since the user is clicking on a link, it only makes sense making that link convey the information you're after. Just pass any data you want in the URL, e.g. as a a query string parameter:

1. `http://example.com/page_x?bgcolor=1`
2. `http://example.com/page_x?bgcolor=2`
3. `http://example.com/page_x?bgcolor=3`

Then you can just query for this in the [page template](http://www.wordpressmax.com/customize-wordpress/custom-page) like so:

```
<?php
  /*
  Template Name: Varying Background Color Template
  */

  $bgcolor = $_GET['bgcolor'];

  switch ($bgcolor) {
    case 1:
      // Change the background to color 1
      break;

    case 2:
      // Change the background to color 2
      break;

    case 3:
      // Change the background to color 3
      break;
  }
?>
```

If you think query string parameters are ugly, you can use path info instead, but this requires you to create a special case [rewrite rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) that makes the path info "invisible" to WordPress so it doesn't think it's the slug of a page. Whether you want or need this depends on how your permalink configuration in WordPress is.

Comment: I also found this after more searching and it uses a similar approach. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-variables-on-custom-admin-pages.  It says that plugins that need to pass data between pages also use your GET method.

Answer (score -2):

1. you have to create your page as a wp template ( if you did not created already ) ( [see this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) )
2. you are right with the session variable. pass the variable to that page and process it there. there is a bit of programming involved...

I do not know of another way for doing what you ask.