# POSTing multidimensional array to the server via PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [multi-dimensional array post from form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719087/multi-dimensional-array-post-from-form)

I would like to send some data from the client to the PHP server using jQuery `$.post()`.  When it arrives at the server, I would like `$_POST['myList']` to be equal to either of the following (what ever is easiest).  What should I set the data object to within `$.post()`?

```
array (
  0=>array('id'=>123,'d1'=>'aaa','d2'=>'xxx'),
  1=>array('id'=>234,'d1'=>'bbb','d2'=>'yyy'),
  2=>array('id'=>345,'d1'=>'ccc','d2'=>'zzz')
)

array (
  123=>array('d1'=>'aaa','d2'=>'xxx'),
  234=>array('d1'=>'bbb','d2'=>'yyy'),
  345=>array('d1'=>'ccc','d2'=>'zzz')
)
```

Comment: you can use json format to send data from javascript to server, and on the server side decode it.

Comment: There are no multidimensional arrays like this in javascript, you would need to send something else and convert it to whatever you like on the serverside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: first one looked like a simple array of objects, but seems jQuery needs this to be a keyed object:

```
var send_this = {
  0: { id: 123, d1: 'aaa', d2: 'xxx' },
  1: { id: 234, d1: 'bbb', d2: 'yyy' },
  2: { id: 345, d1: 'ccc', d2: 'zzz' }
};
```

Second looks just has different looking keys for object containing objects:

```
var send_this = {
  '123': { d1: 'aaa', d2: 'xxx' },
  '234': { d1: 'bbb', d2: 'yyy' },
  '345': { d1: 'ccc', d2: 'zzz' }
};
```

Tested implementation in jQuery 1.7.1:

```
$.post( '/herp.php', send_this, function(d) {
    console.info( d );
});
```

The PHP program receives data exactly as you want it in $_POST.

Comment: Before posting the question, I tried something like this, but it is just passed as text and PHP can't reconstruct it.

Comment: My bad.  Your solution works great!

Answer (score 2):

You should use a JSON strong to send the data: Here is an example:

```
var pushData = {
        id: "blalal",
        id: "blalal",
        id: "blalal",
    };
JSON.stringify(pushData)
```

and then you can just post it or whatever

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://blalallalalal="+JSON.stringify(pushData),
    type : "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function() {
        // alert("fsdf");
    }
});
```

then from php side just use

```
$data = get_object_vars(json_decode($dataJSON));
```

DONE

Answer (score 1):

Option 1

```
var data = [
  { id: 123, d1: 'aaa', d2: 'xxx' },
  { id: 234, d1: 'bbb', d2: 'yyy' },
  { id: 345, d1: 'ccc', d2: 'zzz' }
];
```

Option 2

```
var data = {
  '123': { d1: 'aaa', d2: 'xxx' },
  '234': { d1: 'bbb', d2: 'yyy' },
  '345': { d1: 'ccc', d2: 'zzz' }
};
```

then

```
$.post(url, {mylist: data});
```

Comment: Same great solution as pp19dd.  Don't know which one was first.

Comment: More importantly @user1032531, this is a code-only answer that will not go very far to educate/empower future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

You could send them as three arrays, one for each attribute.

```
myList_id[]=123&myList_d1[]=aaa&myList_d2[]=xxx&myList_id[]=234&...
```

In PHP, you will recieve them as `$_POST['myList_id']`, `$_POST['myList_d1']` and `$_POST['myList_d2']`, which you could combine into your desired array.

Or if you include indices, you could go a step further:

```
myList[0][id]=123&myList[0][d1]=aaa&myList[0][d2]=xxx&myList[1][id]=234&...
```

which will give you the array directly: `$_POST['myList']`

Answer (score 0):

If your using jQuerys `$.post` or `$.get`, you ***do not*** need to encode/decode, just pass a JS object as the data argument...

```
var data = {
  "myList" : {
    0 : {"id":1,...etc},
    1 : {"id":2,...etc},
    2 : {"id":3,...etc},
    etc...
  }
};


// post or get
$.post(
  url2post,
  data,
  callbackFunc
);
```

Comment: This looks very similar to pp19dd's and Musa's answer.  I had previously tried something like this, but it didn't work.  Probably operator error.  Let me retest.