# Separating related form fields into multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Is it possible to create a multidimensional $_POST array that contains related fields? (CompanyName, CompanyAddress, CompanyPhone) (HomePhone, HomeAddress, HomeState) What I would like to do is when I click submit I essentially have two arrays inside of the $_POST array like this:

```
   $_POST['CompanyInfo']['CompanyName']
   $_POST['CompanyInfo']['CompanyAddress'] 
   $_POST['CompanyInfo']['CompanyPhone'] 

   $_POST['HomeInfo']['HomePhone']
   $_POST['HomeInfo']['HomeState']
   $_POST['HomeInfo']['HomeAddress']
```

Comment: similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719087/multi-dimensional-array-post-from-form

Answer (score 0):

Setting up your form's input names properly will allow you to accomplish this.

Consider `<input name="CompanyInfo[CompanyName]" type="text" />` could be accessed with `$_POST['CompanyInfo']['CompanyName']`