# PHP form multiple dynamically added form

Tags: php, forms

I have a form where the user can fill it and then if he need can add more field (I did it with js) by pushing a button.
Now I would like to post via php the result but I don't know how to write the php side. I did try to follow directions in [multi-dimensional array post from form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719087/multi-dimensional-array-post-from-form) but I could not sort it out.
My html form:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="form.php">
<label>Ice Age Gelato</label>
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
<div class="multi-fields"><div class="multi-field">
<input type="text" name="user[]">
<button type="button"   class="remove-field">Remove</button>
</div></div>
<button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Send"> 
</form>
```

And this the relative part in form.php that I don't know how to write:

```
$user = $_POST['users'] = array(
array()
);
```

and:

```
user: $user,
```

Where is wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using input field as a string as:

```
<input type="text" name="user[]">
```

Than you will result the result as like that:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);

Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
        )    
    [submit] => Submit Query
)
```

Now how can you get the users from this this multidimensional `array`:

As mentioned in other answers you will get the values as:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
print_r($user);

// Result
Array
(
    [0] => test
)
```

Now how can you get this value from an `array`, follow this:

```
foreach ($user as $value) {
    echo $value. "<br/>"; // test
}
```

Comment: So in the form.php I should write:
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);

Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
        )    
    [submit] => Submit Query
)
$user = $_POST['user'];
print_r($user);

// Result
Array
(
    [0] => test
)
foreach ($user as $value) {
    echo $value. "<br/>"; // test
}
All together?

Comment: @MassimilianoRubino: no, it just an example... how to get the valuues from form, your form is fine... u only need this in php... $user = $_POST['user'];
print_r($user);

Comment: Yes, thanks. With this I print in the form.php but not in the email, how to transfer in the email?

Comment: @MassimilianoRubino: can u show your email code?? do u want to show all emails in email body???

Comment: @MassimilianoRubino: use this: $user = implode(",",$_POST['user']); instead of $user = $_POST['user'];

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$user = $_POST['users'] = array(
   array()
);
```

To

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
```

1. You are replacing the post values with your `array()` definition.
2. You used `user` as input name and trying to get `users` from posted data.

> Note: By defining input name as `user[]`, you have already changed the value format to `array`. So no need to take an extra action to make it an `array` when getting it from posted data. You will get `$_POST['user']` as an array with all input values as items. For example if you have two input values with "userA" and "userB". `var_dump($_POST['user'])` will give you like this -

```
Array (
 [0] => "userA",
 [1] => "userB",
)
```

**EDIT**

As you are trying to print `$users` as string to send to email, but it is an array. So, just join the array elements with comma to make it a string. Like this:

```
<? $user = $_POST['user']; mail("info@ice-cream-showcase.com" , "test" , "user: ".join(",",$user) , "From: $email\n "); ?>
```

Comment: I fill 3 field with 3 different random words and this is what I get in the email: user: Array,

Comment: You cannot just echo / print an array, you need to iterate over each item in array and then print. Pls show your codes for sending email, so that we can better help.

Comment: <? 
$user = $_POST['user'];


mail("info@ice-cream-showcase.com" , "test" , "user: $user," , "From: $email\n "); // email

mail($email, "Ice", "Thanks", "From: info@ice-cream-showcase.com"); // user email
 ?>    http://iceagethai.com/form_php.txt

Answer (score 0):

As your input name is `user[]` so replace

```
$user = $_POST['users'] = array(
    array()
);
```

to

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
```

Comment: In this way, even if I fill 4 fiels I just receive the word "Array" in the email

Comment: If you have 5 fields then when you `print_r($_POST);` then you will get `Array ( [user] => Array ( [0] => test1@gmail.com [1] => test2@gmail.com [2] => test3@gmail.com [3] => test4@gmail.com [4] => test5@gmail.com ) )`