# file type input not working in a loop

Tags: php, html, css, blob

i am trying to upload a pic and create a copy of it inside a folder named images but it wont work during the loop, can you help me solve the problem? here's my code;

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM product";
$q=$conn->query($sql);
while($r=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$code= $r['prod_code']; 
    <table class="table" width=200% >
                                    <tr>
                                    <th colspan=6 style="background-color: lightgray"> </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th>Add variant </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th>Image</th>
                                    <th>color</th>
                                    <th>Size</th>
                                    <th>Size Type</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td><input type="file" name="image" id="image" style="width: 80px" required /></td>
                                    <form method="POST">
                                    <td><input type="text" name="addcolor" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; border-radius: 0px"  required/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="addsize" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; border-radius: 0px "  required/></td>
                                    <td><select name="addtype"  class="form-control"  style="width: 150px; border-radius: 0px"  required ><option value="International">International </option>
                                    <option value="US">US </option>
                                    <option value="UK">UK</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="addquantity" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; border-radius: 0px"  required/></td>
                                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="addprod" value="<?php echo $code; ?>" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>
                                    </form>
                                    </tr>

                                    </table>  
}
```

heres the php:

```
if(isset($_POST['addprod'])){

            $prodcode= $_POST['addprod'];
            $color= $_POST['addcolor'];
            $size= $_POST['addsize'];
            $type= $_POST['addtype'];
            $quantity= $_POST['addquantity'];

            $image=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
            $image_name=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $image_size=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"images/".$_FILES['image']['name']);
            $location="images/".$_FILES['image']['name'];

            $sql7 = "INSERT into color_variation (prod_code,color_pic,color,size,size_type,quantity) values('$prodcode','$location','$color','$size','$type','$quantity')";
            $q7 = $conn->query($sql7);
        }
```

it will only save the name of the folderand a slash, and it produces errors. help me with this please

Comment: anyone? please, huhu'

Comment: Could you check the contents of $_FILES?

Comment: You have PHP and HTML intermingled. PHP code should be enclosed in `<?php` and `?>`. Also note that only one input with the same name will be processed. You'll likely want to give these unique names.

Comment: yeah i know in my real code in here i did that,

Comment: how should i gave them a unique name since its in loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error into your first piece of code, I fixed it and it looks like this. Also I changes name for inputs (from `addcolor` to `addcolor[]`)to work with them as with arrays into your second piece of code (see how to [work with multi-dimensional array post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719087/multi-dimensional-array-post-from-form)):

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
$q = $conn->query($sql);
while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $code = $r['prod_code']; ?>
    <table class="table" width=200%>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=6 style="background-color: lightgray"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Add variant</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>color</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Size Type</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" style="width: 80px" required/></td>
            <form method="POST">
                <td><input type="text" name="addcolor[]" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; border-radius: 0px"
                           required/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="addsize[]" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; border-radius: 0px "
                           required/></td>
                <td><select name="addtype[]" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; border-radius: 0px" required>
                        <option value="International">International</option>
                        <option value="US">US</option>
                        <option value="UK">UK</option>
                    </select></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="addquantity[]" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; border-radius: 0px"
                           required/></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="addprod[]" value="<?php echo $code; ?>"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>

    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: in my original code in here is the same with this now how to solve my problem?

Comment: You need also to work with your post data as with multi array (see answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719087/multi-dimensional-array-post-from-form)

Comment: than so much , thats what i forgot.