# I want to know about sending array values from one page to another

Tags: php, arrays

I want to know how to send a filled 2d array from one page to another in php. After filling the array in page 1 I want to use the array in page 2.Can you suggest me the easiest way..

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - How to send an array to another page ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548159/php-how-to-send-an-array-to-another-page)

Comment: Easiest way depends on the context. But you never tell us the real case, so, you will never get proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Save it in the $_SESSION variable like this:

```
$_SESSION['data'] = array(array(1,2),array(3,4));
```