# How to read an array from another php page

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have the below mentioned code (actually, configuration) written in a file (config.php) and i want to get the content written in config.php in another file (check.php)

**Codes written in config.php:**

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'id' => 'asd5646asdas',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '5.0.12',
);
```

**Code written in check.php to get the content is:**

```
$config_file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'config.php';
$config = file_get_contents($config_file_path);
```

Using the above code i am getting the output as a string and i wanted to convert it into an array. To do so, i have tried the below code.

```
$config = substr($config, 24, -5); // to remove the php starting tag and other un-neccesary things

$config = str_replace("'","",$config);
$config_array = explode("=>", $config);
```

Using the above code, i am getting an output like:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>   id 
    [1] =>  asd5646asdas,
  dbtype 
    [2] =>  mysql,
  version 
    [3] =>  5.0.12
)
```

which is incorrect.

Is there any way to convert it into an array. I have tried serialize() as well as mentioned in [accessing array from another page in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318452/accessing-array-from-another-page-in-php) , but did not succeed.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: You may include the file. If you want to *parse* the array, you might check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17118032/). There is a [custom php parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17134904/) and a [regex solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17134110/) in the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple

```
include_file "config.php";
```

Comment: Oh, yes... I really forget this approach.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need `file_get_contents`:

```
require_once 'config.php'
var_dump($CONFIG);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use include or require to include and execute the file. The difference is just what happens when the file doesn't exist. `inlcude` will throw a warning, `require` an error.
To make sure just to load (and execute) the file the first time you can also use `include_once`, `require_one` [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
If you are somehow not able to include the file (what reasons ever) take a look at the `eval()` [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to execute php code from string. But  this is not recommendet at all because of security reasons!

```
require_once('config.php');
include_once('config.php');
require('config.php');
include('config.php');
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm very confused at your approach, if you just do this:

```
include(config.php);
```

Then your $CONFIG variable will be available on other pages.

```
print_r($CONFIG);
```

Take a look on the [PHP website which documents the include function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using codeigniter no need to include the config file, you can access using $this, but if you are using plain php, u need to use include() or require() or include_once() or require_once()

Comment: Yes, i am using codeigniter but the config.php file is located outside of the framework. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

How could you fail to read about the [`require_once`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) directive? :)

```
$config = file_get_contents($config_file_path);
```

Must be:

```
require_once $config_file_path;
// now you can use variables, classes and function from this file
var_dump($config);
```

If you follow the link [to the `require_once` manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) please read also about `include` and `include_once`. As a PHP developer you MUST know about this. It's elementary